# React Native syntax highlighting

Tags: react-native, syntax-highlighting, expo

I want to use syntax highlighting of code for my React Native app, but i can not find it. I have found syntax highlighting of code only for react, but not for React Native.

I want to find smt like this: 
Let's say that i have html code that i want to highlight, how i can do this, without using render-html.

If you did not understand, this is syntax highlighting: https://pinetools.com/syntax-highlighter

And i need to have it for React Native. Is there any npm or yarn packages for this?

Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe react-native-syntax-highlighter?
GitHub link: 
https://github.com/conorhastings/react-native-syntax-highlighter

Comment: i have already tried this, but i can not download it with yarn

Comment: look, when i added to my react native expo project with npm, i needed to exchange all added packages from yarn to npm, but i did not want to do this. When i tried to add with yarn: yarn add react-native-syntax-highlighter it was said that there is no package

Comment: Hmm, there is react-native-syntax-highlighter on Yarn. I'm not sure why it says that, are you sure you spelled it correctly?

Comment: Great! it would be cool if you set this as correct answer :D So other people can see this package